# Why use the language of לֹא-תְבַשֵּׁל גְּדִי, בַּחֲלֵב אִמּוֹ

Tags: midrash, meat-and-milk

The concept of לֹא-תְבַשֵּׁל גְּדִי, בַּחֲלֵב אִמּוֹ is brought down three times in the Torah. The Gemarah learns from this that there are three prohibitions: 1) The prohibition against cooking milk and meat 2) The prohibition of eating milk and meat together 3) the prohibition against deriving any benefit from a cooked mixture of milk and meat.

Why does the Torah use the same language to indicate three different things? Why isn't the verb used to separate each of the three prohibitions used in the Torah?

Comment: They are all about eating

Comment: @DoubleAA only 1 is about eating. The others are not.

Comment: Depends how narrowly you take "eating".

Comment: Sanhedrin uses the same logic with the clause "el ha'elokim" to enumerate three dayanim for a court.

Comment: @DoubleAA even if you have a different definition of eating, it still should not say לֹא-תְבַשֵּׁל

Comment: @Bochur613 But you can't eat it (in a prohibited way) until it has been cooked. You want it to say: Don't eat that which was cooked?

Comment: Unless someone gives an answer as to why specifically these words were chosen, doesn't make sense: Do not cook, do not eat, do not derive benefit

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt it's "chol." El ha-elohim. "The authorities", not "the Almighty."

Comment: The Gemara, as far as I can tell, doesn't learn it from the fact that it's phrased this way, but simply because it's repeated 3 times.

Comment: And it's certainly possible that the Torah phrased it this way because it **only** meant that you shouldn't *"cook a kid in its mother's milk."*  The other prohibitions are Rabbinic inventions.  (In support of this, the Ramban (Devarim 14:21), for example, claims that the juxtaposition of "Kedoshim Tihiyu" and "Lo Tevashel" teaches us that the mixture is not inherently despicable, but rather represents human cruelty.  Therefore, while cooking a kid in its mother's milk is obviously bad, there should be no reason why I couldn't eat poultry cooked in cow's milk.)

Answer (score 1):

This exact question is asked on the [Daat website](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/sinay/basar.htm), and they answer as follows:

> If the Torah had written "Don't eat a kid in its mother's milk," it would have prohibited all such forms.  Therefore the Torah wrote "cook" to be lenient and only prohibit eating via cooking ("אכילה דרך בישול").  (See Chullin 108a)  The word "cook" also serves to be more stringent that the word "eat," for "cook" prohibits this act even if one does not benefit from it. (See Pesachim 25a).
>
> The Rambam (Forbidden Foods 9:2) answer this question by saying it's a *kal v'chomer:* The Torah says "cooking" which includes "eating."

*(Translation is mine; Can't copy-paste because Daat has messed-up character encoding; article continues [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/sinay/basar2.htm))*